# Autocad C# String repeating same value then add pages

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I have custom autocad plugin which will convert drawings to pdf, save them to output directory and name them based on text string value form a block reference.

The code works flawlessly. The only problem is it can handle when the p.viewname is repeated in vtbl more than once.

Each drawing has a tag and if the value of those tags are same the pdf should add page to the pdf rather than overwriting other and only create the one which is last in selection.

```
string pdfFile = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(outdir, pdfname), "pdf");
p.viewName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pdfname);                                     
using (Transaction tr = doc.Database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
using (ViewTable vtbl = tr.GetObject(doc.Database.ViewTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as ViewTable)
{
    if (vtbl.Has(p.viewName))
    {
        using (ViewTableRecord vtr = tr.GetObject(vtbl[p.viewName], OpenMode.ForWrite) as ViewTableRecord)
        {
            vtr.CenterPoint = p.center;
            vtr.Width = p.Width;
            vtr.Height = p.Height;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var vtr = new ViewTableRecord();
        vtr.Name = p.viewName;
        vtr.CenterPoint = p.center;
        vtr.Width = p.Width;
        vtr.Height = p.Height;
        vtbl.Add(vtr);
        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(vtr, true);
    }
    tr.Commit();
}
PublishViews2MultiSheet(new List<Page>() { p }, pdfFile);
```

Comment: I'm not sure which part of this you need help with -- can you clarify your question, please?

Comment: if p.filename value is repeated in vtbl then add pages.

Comment: Are you iterating through a collection?  The sample you provided seems to only be doing one page at a time.  I see that when you run the "PublishViews2MultiSheet" command, you're creating a new list at that time and just using your single page in it's place.  It seems to me what you need to do is compile a dictionary, put any pages with the same name under a single key and then iterate through that dictionary when its time to print.